# Custom property(list) in propertygrid return ,,Constructor type collection was not found" in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I have an application in WindowsForms and i use control propertyGrid.
I set a SelectedObject property to my custom object. But one property like this:

```
[CategoryAttribute("Options"), DescriptionAttribute("")]
[TypeConverter(typeof(Language))]
public List<Language> Languages { get; set; }
```

return me ,,Constructor type Language was not found"

Other string or enum property work fine.
There is a code of Language class:

```
public class Language
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string ISOCode { get; set; }
        public string LocaleCode { get; set; }

        public Language(int id, string name, string code, string isoCode, string localeCode)
        {
            this.ID = id;
            this.Name = name;
            this.Code = code;
            this.ISOCode = isoCode;
            this.LocaleCode = localeCode;
        }
    }
```

Thank you for any answer

Comment: Try adding a default constructor to `Language` and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add a default constructor like this:

```
public Language()
{
    // Set default values or leave empty
}
```

Comment: I try it add previously, but i have same problem.

Comment: Ah i am an idiot.... I take Language from other project and there is a debug form, but references was set to Release... Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: take care and feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

I try it add previously, but i have same problem.

There is an image.

Translation
Chyba (Error)
Konstruktor typu Nextis.Eshop9.Entities.Language nebyl nalezen.
(Constructor type Nextis.Eshop9.Entities.Language was not found.)

but other properties(string, enum etc.) i can edit.

[Property languages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4M8i.png)